# For and While loops

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

I am practicing while loops and i am trying to come up with different formula that i used in for loops to do the same and i want to know if its possible to do it.

```
Database=["Akaki","Salome","Giorgi","Lasha","Beqa"]    
x=0    
for i in Database:  
  while x<len(Database):    
    x+=1  
    print(f"{x} {i}")
```

This is what I tried and answer I got is

```
1 Akaki  
2 Akaki  
3 Akaki  
4 Akaki  
5 Akaki
```

And I want to numerate it correctly with correct names in for loops. I have this formula to do it:

```
Database= ["Akaki","Salome","Giorgi","Lasha","Beqa"]  
for i in range(len(Database)):  
  print(i,Database[i])
```

That does the job but can I do it with while loops as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the index in 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible:

```
x=0    
while x<len(Database):      
    print(f"{x} {Database[x]}")
    x+=1
```

You don't need two nested loops in your first example.

Answer (score 0):

The Pythonic way is to use `enumerate`.  It returns a default 0-based index and a value for each item in the iterable:

```py
Database = ['Akaki', 'Salome', 'Giorgi', 'Lasha', 'Beqa']    
for i, value in enumerate(Database, start=1):
    print(f'{i} {value}')
```

Output:

```
1 Akaki
2 Salome
3 Giorgi
4 Lasha
5 Beqa
```